# How do I install bindfs in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10

When I try to install the package `bindfs` in 11.10 it complains that it can't find the package `fuse`. How can I install `bindfs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a known packaging 11.10 bug for the `bindfs` package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bindfs/+bug/851600) that remains unresolved.

**Workaround 1. Dummy `fuse` package**

Note that this requires a bit of fiddling, and the link below is in German. However, it does not suffer from the drawbacks of the second workaround. (Thanks to [bmhm](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bindfs/+bug/851600/comments/13) for this solution. If you can translate the link, feel free to edit this answer and include the translation here.)

> [This workaround] will not interfere with any other packages. A quick and clean solution is to install a virtual package "fuse", which depends on fuse-utils.
>
> Check my blog on how to create such a package:
>   http://blog.bmarwell.de/2012/01/10/ubuntu-bindfs-mit-abhangigkeit-von-fuse-installieren/
>   (the first grey box contains the control file content)

**Workaround 2. Alternate version of `bindfs`**

You will need to find and install a version of `bindfs` that does not depend on `fuse`. For example, a `.deb` from a trusted source. However, it will not automatically upgrade should a new version come along. Two packages that seem trustworthy have been added to the comment of the original bug:

- [32-bit](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bindfs/+bug/851600/comments/7) version
- [64-bit](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bindfs/+bug/851600/comments/2) versions

Download the one that matches your system and double-click it. It will open in Software Centre. Install it. `bindfs` will now work. (It will also appear greyed out in Update Manager from this point forward. A small price to pay IMHO :) )

**Choosing a workaround**

Workaround 1 requires more work, but will be upgraded if a solution is ever made. Workaround 2 requires less work, but will not be upgraded. If you pick workaround 2, you could subscribe to the bug on Launchpad, and you will be notified if it is closed.

This issue appears to be resolved in 12.04 LTS (tested in Beta 1). I'm not sure how either workaround will fare when upgrading to 12.04. Be prepared to purge and reinstall `bindfs`.